# Generate static tiles with current OSM style from PostGIS

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm trying to generate static tiles for Great Britain with the current OSM style. I have populated my PostGIS database from a osm.pbf file from here [1]. I have Mapnik version 3.0.9 installed.

I can generate tiles using the polytiles.py script from [2] but they use the old OSM styles. The polytiles.py script only accepts xml style sheets but the new OSM styles are not xml [3].

Is there another script I can use instead of polytiles.py to do the same thing?

[1] http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain.html
[2] http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/mapnik
[3] https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto.git

Comment: CartoCSS-based stylesheets can be converted to XML, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/mapnik-rendering-with-osm-carto-style and https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/30985/where-to-get-the-standard-osm-style-file-for-mapnik and https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/CartoCSS. I'm posting this as a comment because it would be obviously a low quality (= link-only) answer. Feel free to post a good answer based on these solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using the following steps...

1. Install [Carto](https://github.com/mapbox/carto) with the following command... `npm install carto`
2. Convert the CartoCSS-based stylesheets to XML using `carto project.mml > osm.xml`
3. Pass the new osm.xml file as an argument to polytiles.py.